# Issues/Questions extending a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using an [open source scrollbar component](https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars/blob/master/src/Scrollbars/index.js) in my react app.

I have extended the component so that it looks like this:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Scrollbars from "react-custom-scrollbars";

//  This component extends react-custom-scrollbars and allows
//  the developer to force an update of the scrollbars
//  every 'X' ms.

class ForcedScrollbars extends Scrollbars {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.rerenderTimer = setInterval(() => {
            this.update();
        }, this.props.forceRerenderTimer);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
         clearInterval(this.rerenderTimer);

    }
}

ForcedScrollbars.propTypes = {
    forceRerenderTimer: PropTypes.number
};

export default ForcedScrollbars;
```

I have two questions.

1. The `componentDidMount` method in the parent component `Scrollbars` looks like this:

   ```
   componentDidMount() {
      this.addListeners();
      this.update();
      this.componentDidMountUniversal();
   }
   ```

In my `ForcedScrollbars` component will the same methods get called in the `ForcedScrollbars` `componentDidMount` call or do I have to call them again explicitly? i.e.

```
class ForcedScrollbars extends Scrollbars {

    componentDidMount() {
       this.addListeners();
       this.update();
       this.componentDidMountUniversal();
       this.rerenderTimer = setInterval(() => {
          this.update();
       }, this.props.forceRerenderTimer);
    }

  // REST OF COMPONENT //
```

2. I am seeing an error in the console

> Warning: Unknown prop forceRerenderTimer on  tag. Remove this
>   prop from the element. For details, see ...(facebook link)...

As you can see in my code above I have the following which doesn't appear to work.

```
ForcedScrollbars.propTypes = {
    forceRerenderTimer: PropTypes.number
};
```

Also I have tried which didn't appear to work either.

```
Scrollbars.propTypes = {
    forceRerenderTimer: PropTypes.number
};
```

Check [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/YEo1LvmWO) here.

Comment: Add the `contructor` with the call to `super(props)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to extend `Scrollbars` property types

```
ForcedScrollbars.propTypes = {
   ...Scrollbars.propTypes,
   forceRerenderTimer: PropTypes.number
}
```

Or if you are not using `object-rest-spread`

```
ForcedScrollbars.propTypes = Object.assign(
   {},
   Scrollbars.propTypes,
   { forceRerenderTimer: PropTypes.number }
)
```

**Update**

`Scrollbars` simply dumps all the properties it "doesn't know" to the root tag specified [code](https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars/blob/master/src/Scrollbars/index.js#L499). So every property you add to the extended component will be added to the `tagName` specified.

You have the following options here:

1. Ask `react-custom-scrollbars` maintainer to implement more intelligent prop filtering system. Say buy using `propTypes`.
2. Do some hackery by providing a custom stateless component that omits `forceRerenderTimer` property. [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/jxjQNDW4) (`unknowProp` was added just for sanity check).

Code

```
class ForcedScrollbars extends Scrollbars {
    static propTypes = {
      ...Scrollbars.propTypes,
      forceRerenderTimer: PropTypes.number,
      // allow components as root
      tagName: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.func
      ])
    };

    static defaultProps = {
      ...Scrollbars.defaultProps,
      // omit forceRerenderTimer
      tagName: allProps => {
        const {
          forceRerenderTimer,
          ...props,
        } = allProps

        return createElement('div', props)
      },
    }
```

Comment: yeah, that doesn't appear to be working. It could be something to do with how the parent component works - https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars/blob/master/src/Scrollbars/index.js If you check the render method I am sure that it was showing me the same error until I also added `forceRerenderTimer` into const `{forceRerenderTimer} = this.props;`

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Could you provide a fiddle demostrating the issue. This should work.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/YEo1LvmWO - error isn't showing here for some reason, even without any prop type check.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Check this workaround https://codesandbox.io/s/jxjQNDW4. BTW consider using composition over inheritance.

Comment: cheers for the answer, and good shout on looking at composition over inheritance! just reading the docs on it now!